# Not able to reset the grid on deleting a row in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a functionality where i have to reset the grid on click of delete button.
This used to work earlier with the below code but my screen was getting freezed.
**Please find the below code where my reset was working but my screen was getting freezed on click of delete button.**

```
<p:commandButton id="Delete" action="#{bean.id}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" value="Delete" title="GDeleteButton" ajax="false" onclick="PF('Confirm').show();" type="button">
<p:confirm header="Delete Record" message="Are you sure about deleting this record?" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
</p:commandButton>

    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" widgetVar="Confirm">
    <p:commandButton title="GDelYesButton" value="Yes" oncomplete="PF('Confirm').hide()" " />
    <p:commandButton title="GDelNoButton" value="No" onclick="PF('Confirm').hide()" type="button" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
```

**I made changes with the below code for removing the freezing issue and then my grid reset stopped working. Please find the below code.**

I had added the below code for confirm dialog box.

```
styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"
styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"
```

**Newly Code:**

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
    <p:commandButton title="GDelYesButton" value="Yes" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"/>
    <p:commandButton title="GDelNoButton" value="No" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How could your `Delete` button perform a non-ajax call to `#{bean.id}` action method being it `type="button"`? You've got redundant code there. Check if you want it to perform a call to the server or it just has to display the dialog itself (client side behaviour).

Comment: @XtremeBiker : I need to make a ajax call on click of Yes button. But currently now what is happening when i click on delete button, the screen gets freezed/blocked. But as you said the call goes to the server if i am clicking on Enter button and the functionality works as desired. The issue is i am not able to use Mouse as i cant click on the dialog.

Comment: Your delete button must implement just client side behaviour.

Comment: @XtremeBiker : I did try that but that time if i click on yes button there is no action getting performed(screen is not freezed though). In my case i am able to do achieve my functionality through keyboard but i am facing issue through mouse(screen freezed).

Comment: That's because you're not calling any action at all in your dialog's 'yes' button...